# How to use Git to to merge code from plain files

Tags: git, git-merge, git-diff

I'm looking for a way to use Git, or take recommendations on any Git clients that may have powerful merge tools to resolve an issue that can be summarised as:

1. Code was deployed to a server, unknown version / date
2. Code was "developed", *on... server...* extensively
3. Code in the repo changed with the inexorable march of time... extensively
4. Code written on the server needs to be integrated with latest version

I've tried creating a branch from master and then pasting the updated code from the server on top of the working copy. From this I can see the diff, **but committing these changes would overwrite changes from master, it's not really a merge.**

How can I leverage git to merge the code in a way that would only need to deal with the conflicts manually and potentially have the rest merged automatically? (Obviously understanding that it may not build, run tests or be logically correct)

I suspect that if I knew the date that the code was taken from the repo and deployed to the server, that I could branch from master at a commit in that timeframe, and apply the modified server changes on that branch, and then try and merge that to the current master.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have a bunch of code developed outside of version control and you want to merge it?

Answer (score 1):

Make an "orphan" branch, one that has no prior history. Add and commit the old code to that repo. Make sure it has the same directory structure as your code in master. Then merge the two branches with `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories`.

1. `git switch --orphan live-code`
2. Adjust the directory structure to match master.
3. `git add .`
4. `git commit`
5. `git checkout master`
6. `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories live-code`
7. Enjoy the conflicts.

Alternatively, make your best guess when the code diverged, make a branch from that point in master, and go from there. That *might* make the job easier if you guess correctly.

Comment: Thanks @schwern those sound like good options. I've not heard of an orphan branch before. I'll  try those and  accept the answer